# Angular 4 to 9 RequestOptions

Tags: angular

We are attempting to upgrade from Angular 4 to Angular 9. I have successfully upgraded all our packages defined in Package.json.

Problem I have at the moment is that RequestOptions in @angular/http have been deprecated and I'm having trouble trying to find the equivalent in Angular 9.

original Code:

```
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

private getDefaultRequestOptionsObservable(headers: Headers = null): Observable<RequestOptions> {
        return this.userService.getUser()
            .flatMap(user => {
                if (headers == null) {
                    headers = new Headers();
                }

                let userSessionHeader = headers.get(this.userSessionHeaderName);

                if (userSessionHeader == null || userSessionHeader === '') {
                    headers.append(this.userSessionHeaderName, user.userSession);
                }

                return Observable.of(new RequestOptions({ withCredentials: true, headers: headers }));
            });
    }
```

I have replaced my imports with:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
```

and i'm also importing 'of' from rxjs ready to remove the explicit return Observable.of(.....) to return of(...)

if anyone can help me out re-writing the above would be great. I have replaced the method signature with :

```
private getDefaultRequestOptionsObservable(headers: Headers = null): Observable<HttpRequest<any>> {
```

any help with the `return of(new HttpRequest......` would be appreciated.

Comment: `RequestOptions` closest replacement is `HttpRequest`,  Refer this https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#angularhttp